# Situation of char8_t / UTF8 chars pre-C++17 and poor-man-ing it?

Tags: c++, utf-8, char

I've been reading links as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56762869/preparing-for-char8-t-in-c-17/) and of course [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42900323/absent-stdu8string-in-c11) on preparing for the upcoming "utf8" char type `char8_t` and their corresponding string type in C++20, and can say, up to a point, that it's about time. Also that it's a mess.

Feel free to correct me where I'm wrong:

- C++, any standards, have no means to specify that the source code has a given text encoding (something like Python's `# encoding:...` metadata), nor what Standards can it be compiled into (like say `#!/bin/env g++ -std=c++14`) .
- Up until C++11, there was also no way to specify that any given string literal would have a given encoding - the compiler was free to reparse a UTF8 string literal into say UTF16 or even EBCDIC if it so desired.
- C++11 introduces `u16"text"` and `u32"text"` and associated char types to produce UTF16 and UTF32-encoded text, but does not provide string or stream facilities to work with them, so they're basically useless.
- C++11 *also* introduces `u8"text"` for producing an UTF8-encoded string...
  but does *not even* introduce either a proper UTF8 char type or string type (that's what `char8_t` is intended to be in C++20?), so it's even uselesser than the above.
- Because of all this, when `char8_t` is *finally* introduced, it kills lots of code that was intended to be valid and so far some of the remediations sought include *[disabling char8_t behaviour altogether](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1423r2.html)*.
- Even then, there's no readily available tooling (as in: not the same crap tier interface as `<random>`) to check, transform (within the same string) or convert (copying across string types) text encodings in C++. Even codecvt seems to have been dropped.

Given all of the above, I have some questions regarding why are we in this weird status and if it'll ever get better. Historically Unicode support has been one of the lowest points of C++.

Similarly, am wondering how useful is a poor-man's-emulation of the whole concept  (disclaimer: am the maintainer of [cxxomfort](http://ryan.gulix.cl/fossil.cgi/cxxomfort/), I already backport lots of things. Work needs: *latest* MSVC target at the office is MSVC 2012).

- Why did C++ not add `char8_t` at the proper time when `u8"text"` was introduced or otherwise delay introduction of `u8`?
- Alternatively, why wasn't another, non-breaking prefix like `c8"text"` introduced with `char8_t` in C++20 instead of introducing a wide-scope breaking change? I thought TPTB *hated* breaking changes, even more something that literally breaks the simplest possible case: `cout<< prefix"hello world"`.
- Is `char8_t` intended to functionally be (closer to) an alias of `unsigned char` or of `char`?
- If the former, is working up the way to eg.: `typedef std::basic_string<unsigned char> u8string` a viable emulation strategy? Are there backport / reference implementations available one can look into before writing my own?
- What's the closest we have in C++17-or-below to marking text as (intended to be) UTF-8 *for storage only*?

re: `char8_t` as `unsigned char`, this is more or less what I'm looking at in terms of pseudocode:

```
// this is here basically only for type-distinctiveness
class char8_t {
  unsigned char value;

  public:
  non_explicit constexpr char8_t (unsigned char ch = 0x00) noexcept;
  operator unsigned char () const noexcept;
  // implement all operators to mirror operations on unsigned char
};

// public adapter jic
friend unsigned char to_char (char8_t);

// note we're *not* using our new char-type here
namespace std {
  typedef std::basic_string<unsigned char> u8string;
}

// unsure if these two would actually be needed
// (couldn't make a compelling case so far,
// even testing with Windows's broken conhost)

namespace std {
  basic_istream<char8_t> u8cin;
  basic_ostream<char8_t> u8cout;
}

// we work up operator<<, operator>> and string conversion from there
// adding utf8-validity checks where needed

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream&, std::u8string const&);
std::istream& operator>> (std::istream&, std::u8string&);

// likely a macro; we'll see
#define u8c(ch) static_cast<char8_t>(ch)
// char8_t ch = u8c('x');

// very likely not a macro pre-C++20; can't skip utf-8 validity check on [2]?
u8string u8s (char8_t const* str); // [1], likely trivial
u8string u8s (char const* str);    // [2], non-trivial
// C++20 and up
#define u8s(str) u8##str // or something; not sure

// end result:

// no, I can't even think how would one spell this:
u8string text = u8s("H€łlo Ẅørλd");
// this wouldn't work without refactoring u8string into a full specialization, 
// to add the required constructor, but doing so is a PITA because 
// the basic_string interface is YAIM (yet another infamous mess):
u8string text = u8"H€łlo Ẅørλd";
```

I've tagged this C++ as a general, but this is more about (the value of) implementation for Standards pre-C++20. More importantly, I'm not looking for "*perfect*" solutions or justifications; given the context, poor-man's is more than good enough.

Comment: I think a lot of it comes down to implementing full unicode support properly is a huge amount of work (e.g. see the size of libicu) so the C++ standard has preferred not to implement it at all and leave it up to 3rd party libraries

Comment: I personally wouldn't call `<random>` a "crap tier interface". In my humble opinion it solves real problems, is useful and is a *lot* better than the `srand/rand` crap that C provides.

Comment: Maybe, but when the foremost proposals to fix it start by acknowledgeing something that I've seen in personal experience - that it's much easier to call ``srand`` + ``rand`` than to properly set up the ``random_device``, generator and distribution you need for basically the same effect... the question in my mind is if it was designed to solve esoteric real problems or user real problems.
I like C++ because it's verbose, but when it's *poetic* verbose. ``<random>`` has none of that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm the author of the [P0482](https://wg21.link/p0482) and [P1423](https://wg21.link/p1423) `char8_t` papers.

> Also that it's a mess.

I completely agree.  [SG16](https://github.com/sg16-unicode/sg16) is working to improve all things Unicode and text related, but we're having to start near ground level, so it is going to take a while.

If you haven't seen it yet, the repository linked below provides some utilities for writing code that will work in C++17 and C++20.

- https://github.com/tahonermann/char8_t-remediation

> C++, any standards, have no means to specify that the source code has a given text encoding (something like Python's # encoding:... metadata), nor what Standards can it be compiled into (like say #!/bin/env g++ -std=c++14).

This is correct, but not without precedent.  IBM's xlC compiler supports a [`#pragma filetag`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.cbclx01/zos_pragma_filetag.htm) directive that behaves similarly to Python's encoding declaration.  I started on a paper exploring this space and had hoped to submit it for the Prague meeting, but did not complete it in time.  I expect to submit it for the Varna meeting (in June).

> Up until C++11, there was also no way to specify that any given string literal would have a given encoding - the compiler was free to reparse a UTF8 string literal into say UTF16 or even EBCDIC if it so desired.

Correct, and this technically remained true for `char16_t` and `char32_t` string literals until C++20 and the adoption of [P1041](https://wg21.link/p1041).  Note though that there is no reparsing going on.  In [translation phase 1](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.phases#1.1), the source code contents are converted to the compiler's internal encoding and then in [translation phase 5](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.phases#1.5), character and string literals are converted to the encoding of the appropriate execution character set.

> C++11 introduces u16"text" and u32"text" and associated char types to produce UTF16 and UTF32-encoded text, but does not provide string or stream facilities to work with them, so they're basically useless.

Correct.  [P1629](https://wg21.link/p1629) is one of the more significant changes we're hoping to complete for C++23.  The goal is to provide text encoders, decoders, and transcoders that facilitate working with text at the code unit and code point levels.  We would also provide support for enumerating grapheme clusters.

> C++11 also introduces u8"text" for producing an UTF8-encoded string... but does not even introduce either a proper UTF8 char type or string type (that's what char8_t is intended to be in C++20?), so it's even uselesser than the above.

Correct.  The goal for C++20 was to 1) enable differentiating `"text"` and `u8"text"` in the type system, 2) enable separating locale dependent and UTF-8 text (with enforcement from the type system), 3) ensure use of an unsigned type for UTF-8 code units, and 4) avoid the `char` type aliasing penalty.  That was all we had time to get done for C++20 (standardization is not a rapid process).

> Because of all this, when char8_t is finally introduced, it kills lots of code that was intended to be valid and so far some of the remediations sought include disabling char8_t behaviour altogether.

Correct, `char8_t` was proposed as a breaking change; something not to be taken lightly.  In this case, it was deemed acceptable because 1) code searches found little use of `u8` character and string literals, 2) the options for addressing backward compatibility concerns as discussed in P1423 were considered adequate, and 3) a non-breaking proposal would have added long term baggage to the language for little gain.

> Even then, there's no readily available tooling (as in: not the same crap tier interface as ) to check, transform (within the same string) or convert (copying across string types) text encodings in C++. Even codecvt seems to have been dropped.

Correct.  We'll be working to improve this situation, but it will take time.  `codecvt` has not been dropped (yet); the `<codecvt>` header and various UTF converters were deprecated in C++17.  `std::codecvt` suffers from performance and usability issues, so is not considered something we can continue to build on.  We believe [P1629](https://wg21.link/p1629) is a superior direction.

> Why did C++ not add char8_t at the proper time when u8"text" was introduced or otherwise delay introduction of u8?

I asked one of the C++ committee members who was involved in that original effort.  He told me that he asked the people working on Unicode at the time if a new type should be added and the response was, "eh, we don't need it".

> Alternatively, why wasn't another, non-breaking prefix like c8"text" introduced with char8_t in C++20 instead of introducing a wide-scope breaking change? I thought TPTB hated breaking changes, even more something that literally breaks the simplest possible case: cout<< prefix"hello world".

A different prefix was considered and at one point I briefly favored that approach.  However, as mentioned earlier, that would have left us with two ways of spelling UTF-8 literals and related historical baggage.  In the long run, it was felt that a breaking change, so long as we had reasonable means to mitigate the breakage, offered more benefits.

With regard to that simple test case, take a minute to think about what that code *should* do.  Then go read this: [What is the printf() formatting character for char8_t *?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58878651/what-is-the-printf-formatting-character-for-char8-t/58895428#58895428).

> Is char8_t intended to functionally be (closer to) an alias of unsigned char or of char?

`char8_t` is intentionally and explicitly not an alias (because that has negative performance implications) but is specified to have the same underlying representation as `unsigned char`.  The reason for `unsigned char` over `char` is to avoid expressions like `u8'\x80' < 0` ever evaluating to true (which may or may not be the case with `char` today).

> If the former, is working up the way to eg.: typedef std::basic_string u8string a viable emulation strategy? Are there backport / reference implementations available one can look into before writing my own?

I won't comment on whether this approach is a good idea or not, but it has been done before.  For example, [EASTL has such a typedef](https://github.com/electronicarts/EASTL/blob/master/include/EASTL/string.h#L3909) (That project also provides a [definition of `char8_t` if the native type isn't available](https://github.com/electronicarts/EABase/blob/master/include/Common/EABase/eabase.h#L720-L734))

> What's the closest we have in C++17-or-below to marking text as (intended to be) UTF-8 *for storage only*?

I don't think there is one right answer to this question.  I've seen projects use `unsigned char` or provide a `char8_t` like type via a class.

With regard to your pseudocode, some tweaks to the code in the previously mentioned [char8_t-remediation repository](https://github.com/tahonermann/char8_t-remediation) to provide `unsigned char` types instead of `char` should enable code like the following to work.  See the [definitions of the `_as_char` user-defined literals and `U8` macro](https://github.com/tahonermann/char8_t-remediation/blob/master/char8_t-remediation.h#L89-L97).

```
typedef std::basic_string<unsigned char> u8string;
u8string u8s(U8("text"));
```

Comment: This is tremendously complete (thanks for pointing to the printf question, if I had noticed in advance it was there my question would have been so much shorter!) and wow I had no idea that the final text encoding tasks would go as far as phase 5. Still, it is obvious that this was given more thought than the already large amounts I had expected, so I'll need to go back and forth learning answers and proposals for a while.

Comment: Upon further examination of the linked question it seems to me there is no possible ambiguity about what ``printf`` or ``cout`` usage with UTF8 would do. The thing is, I could have stdout piped or linked to a dot-matrix printer, or even to a teelgraph machine, and the Standard should not *have to* care about that. It should only have to care that the (presumably UTF8) characters I've sent are actually sent to stdout.

Comment: That is a reasonable view point.  But what if `std::cout` is imbued with a `std::codecvt` converter?  If encodings are known, then the implementation can do the right thing.  Otherwise, programmers have the responsibility of ensuring that encodings match or UB ensues (and this seems to be something that is difficult to teach and enforce).  Java takes the approach of, by default, implicitly transcoding from UTF-16 to the current locale when writing via `System.out`.  That helps to reduce bugs.  But we can't add that behavior to iostreams now without it being breaking or requiring an opt-in.

Comment: Requiring an opt-in, or simply designing something better than iostreams, sound like the most sensible solutions. It'd have the advantage of not causing code to break (at runtime, after complining a-OK) before it has a chance to get fixed / improved. Not everyone adds ``<foo/experimental/bar>`` to their projects, in particular in production.

Comment: We're getting `std::u8string` for UTF-8 strings, and we have  `std::cout` and `std::wcout` for `char` and `wchar_t` character data.  But I've seen no discussion of why we should or should not have `std::u8out`.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy, did you see the [linked comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58878651/what-is-the-printf-formatting-character-for-char8-t/58895428#58895428)?